# Draw Line of Regression on scatter plot using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, regression, linear-regression

Using matplotlib i am trying to draw the regression line i calculated using a CSV dataset of pollution.

```
# split the dependent and independent variables
X = df[['O3', 'TEMP', 'PRES', 'DEWP',
       'RAIN', 'wd', 'WSPM']]
y = df["SO2"]

# training and test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

I want to use the values of O3 as x and SO2 as y for this particular scatter plot, as X contains multiple elements i used. the `.iloc[:,0].values` to make sure it is only the first column. However the code below will generate the correct scattergraph but not the regression plot.

```
    # fit the training data to the models
    
    # LINEAR REGRESSION
    linReg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print("Linear Regression Intercept: ",linReg.intercept_ )
    print("Linear Regression Coeffients: ", linReg.coef_)
# compute accuracy using R-squared 

# LINEAR REGRESSION ACCURACY
y_pred = linReg.predict(X_test)

print("Linear Regression Accuracy Score: ", r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
linScore = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)

plt.scatter(X_train.iloc[:,0].values, y_train, edgecolor='k', facecolor='grey', alpha=0.7, label='Sample data')
plt.plot(X_train.iloc[:,0].values, y_pred, color='r')
plt.ylabel('SO2 Values', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('O3 Values', fontsize=14)
plt.legend(facecolor='white', fontsize=11)
```

it generates this traceback.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [25], in <cell line: 10>()
      7 linScore = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
      9 plt.scatter(X_train.iloc[:,0].values, y_train, edgecolor='k', facecolor='grey', alpha=0.7, label='Sample data')
---> 10 plt.plot(X_train.iloc[:,0].values, y_pred, color='r')
     11 plt.ylabel('SO2 Values', fontsize=14)
     12 plt.xlabel('O3 Values', fontsize=14)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:2757, in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2755 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.plot)
   2756 def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2757     return gca().plot(
   2758         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley,
   2759         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:1632, in Axes.plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1390 """
   1391 Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
   1392 
   (...)
   1629 (``'green'``) or hex strings (``'#008000'``).
   1630 """
   1631 kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1632 lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1633 for line in lines:
   1634     self.add_line(line)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:312, in _process_plot_var_args.__call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    310     this += args[0],
    311     args = args[1:]
--> 312 yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:498, in _process_plot_var_args._plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs)
    495     self.axes.yaxis.update_units(y)
    497 if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
--> 498     raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
    499                      f"have shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")
    500 if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    501     raise ValueError(f"x and y can be no greater than 2D, but have "
    502                      f"shapes {x.shape} and {y.shape}")

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (44269,) and (11068,)
```

here is the working scatter graph
[image]

what is wrong with the plot command? am i using the wrong value of x and y?

EDIT: Resizing `X` to be the same size as `y_pred` does produce a line, but i'm not sure why it isnt a best fit regression line but a line connecting these points together

```
X_plot = X_train.iloc[:,0].values
print(X_plot.shape)
print(y_pred.shape)
X_size = np.resize(X_plot,(11068,))
plt.scatter(X_plot, y_train, edgecolor='k', facecolor='grey', alpha=0.7, label='Sample data')
plt.plot(X_size, y_pred, color='r')
plt.ylabel('SO2 Values', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('O3 Values', fontsize=14)
plt.legend(facecolor='white', fontsize=11)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are plotting the train data against the prediction you got from the test data. That's why there is a difference in the dimensions of the inputs resulting in your error.

If plot the predictions made on the training data and plot them against the training data, you wouldn't get an error.

```
y_train_pred = linReg.predict(X_train)

plt.scatter(X_train.iloc[:,0].values, y_train, edgecolor='k', facecolor='grey', alpha=0.7, label='Sample data')
plt.plot(X_train.iloc[:,0].values, y_train_pred, color='r')
plt.ylabel('SO2 Values', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('O3 Values', fontsize=14)
plt.legend(facecolor='white', fontsize=11)
```

To learn more about Linear Regression you can checkout this article - [Gradient Descent (now with a little bit of scary maths)](https://www.ml-concepts.com/2022/04/16/gradient-descent-now-with-a-little-bit-of-scary-maths/).

Answer (score 0):

Try saving `X_train.iloc[:,0]`.values to a variable and then plotting it. Matplotlib is weird like that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: that unfortunately did not  help, it produces the same error about dimension